# Plotting a level curve

Tags: pgfplots

How do I get TikZ to plot the level curve `x^{2}y + xy^{2} = 1`?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    domain=-5:5, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.7854:0.7854,blue] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: could you please add a plot output you have from the code above?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent There is no output of this code it's a MWE.

Comment: @percusse MWE is the code the OP has developed till now? It may contain some output or not? Am I right?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Yes and you can see from the last `addplot` command that the function to be plotted is missing so gives only an axis. But it is useful so that we can directly copy paste and use it.

Comment: @percusse Thank you. I always thought that a MWE may have an output. Sorry if my comment was irrelevant.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent No problem at all. Actually the name is a little misleading such that it might as well be Minimum Nonworking Example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `contour gnuplot` functionality for this, which uses `gnuplot` as a backend for doing the actual calculations.

To compile the document, you need to have `gnuplot` installed on your system and shell escape must be enabled (e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape filename`). PGFPlots makes the necessary `gnuplot` calls automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
\addplot3 [
    very thick,
    contour gnuplot={
        levels=1,
        labels=false,
        draw color=black
    },
    samples=50
] {x^2*y + x*y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does "view={0}{90}" specify about the axes?  How about "levels=1"?

Comment: @Adelyn: See p. 140 and p. 142 (in section 4.6.8 Contour Plots) of the manual.

Comment: So, how can you compile this under MikTeX?

Comment: @AboAmmar: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you get an error message?

Comment: What commands do you need at the command line to make this work? You need at least to call gnuplot on something.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay: No, this is handled internally by PGFPlots. You need to have shell escape enabled.

Comment: @Jake I mean if you are running Windows 7 and you are using a usual editor like `Texmaker`, what is exactly required to get this compiled correctly? Or how to enable `gnuplot`? Because I get the error message: `! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{myFile_contourtmp0.table} could not
be opened.`

Comment: @Jake  I looked on pages 140 and 142 in the manual.  There is nothing there explaining "view={0}{90}."  Also, I would like the level curves plotted on the Cartesian plane ... as graphs of functions of a single variable are typically plotted.

Comment: @Adelyn: Quote from p. 140 of [the manual for version 1.11](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf): "The `view={0}{90}` flag means “view from top”, otherwise the contour lines
would have been drawn as z value". I'm not sure why you say "I would like the level curves plotted on the Cartesian plane". Isn't that what my code does and what the image in my answer shows? Am I misunderstanding something?