# Plot level curve using data from pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, gnuplot

I have some data from some numerical experiments stored in some csv files, which I read into LaTeX using

```
\pgfplotstableread{Results/test.csv}\data
```

These data consist of x, y and z coordinates and I now want to plot the level curve for `z=1`. Several people suggest the usage of gnuplot, e.g. [Plotting a level curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209159/plotting-a-level-curve), which I have tried to adopt for data points with

```
\addplot3 [contour gnuplot={levels={1},labels=false,draw color=black}] table[x={x}, y={y}, z={z}]{\data};
```

which I compile with --shell-escape. This does, however, not work and throw the error

> ExponentialSDE.tex (line 497)
>   Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, processing the input stream did not lead to end-of-scanline markers; the generated temporary file for 'contour external' does not contain any of them (indicating that matrix structure is lost).

I read that one typical problem which gives this error is the lack gnuplot (which makes sense). For my case, gnuplot is installed, this is the terminal output when I run `gnuplot`

```
>>gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 6    last modified 2019-01-01 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2018
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')
```

Do you have any suggestions for what I am doing wrong? and how I can obtain the level curve?

**Full MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
 x y z
    -1    -1     2
    -1     0     1
    -1     1     2
     0    -1     1
     0     0     0
     0     1     1
     1    -1     2
     1     0     1
     1     1     2
}{\data}

\begin{document}
%Not working
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={levels={1},labels=false,draw color=black}] table[x={x}, y={y}, z={z}]{\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%Test for pgfplotstable is properly read
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot table[x={x}, y={y}]{\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like my `compat=newest` is newer than yours because in my case it precisely instructs me what to do:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, processing the input stream did not
>   lead to en d-of-scanline markers; the generated temporary file for
>   'contour external' does  not contain any of them (indicating that
>   matrix structure is lost). To fix thi s, you have the following
>   options:
>    - Insert end-of-scanline markers into your input data (i.e. empty lines),
>    - provide two of the three options 'mesh/rows=, mesh/cols=, mesh/num points='.

Who would resist to follow such a clear instruction? ;-) So I

1. added empty lines to the data and
2. `mesh/rows=3, mesh/cols=3` to the plot command

and got

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
 x y z
    -1    -1     2
    -1     0     1
    -1     1     2

     0    -1     1
     0     0     0
     0     1     1

     1    -1     2
     1     0     1
     1     1     2
}{\data}

\begin{document}
%Now working
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={levels={1},labels=false,draw color=black},
        mesh/rows=3, mesh/cols=3] table[x={x}, y={y}, z={z}]{\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Seems like the error message might have been cut off by my editor.

Comment: @NickyMattsson When was the last time you updated your TeX installation?

Comment: I am running TeX live 2016

Comment: @NickyMattsson I think this is the reason. The newer version comes with a clearer error message/clearer instructions. Some exciting things have happened since 2016. Apart from the above thingy, the `tikzmark` library has now the really cool command `\tikzmarknode` and, most importantly, the `tikzlings` package got added. ;-) So you may want to update.

Comment: I am always terrified of updating my TeX distribution - but this definitely sounds like it would be worth it.